# Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, function, react-hooks

I'm new react typescript developer, here i have a code which works in 'js' 'but when changed to 'tsx' getting error: Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322) it is pointing to 'helperTextt'
error (did not find answer else where)
should i do :     let helperTextt:any = ""; ?

any suggestions ?

```js
let helperTextt = "";

if (event.target.id === "hostname") {
  if (!HOSTNAME_REGEX.test(event.target.value)) {
    helperTextt = (
      <Trans i18nKey="form.formData.hostNameError">
        Invalid Host name
      </Trans>
    );
    errorr = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are assigning a React element(?) to `helperTextt` then you should type it as `let helperTextt: React.Element` (or whatever the concrete type is).

Comment: @FelixKling i did like that and got : 'React' has no exported member named 'Element'. Did you mean 'CElement'?ts(2724)

Comment: Looks like `ReactElement` is exported as named export from the `react` package.

Comment: so what i have to do ?

Answer (score 10):

You could do

```
import { ReactElement } from "react";
```

and then

```
let helperTextt: ReactElement | null = null;
```

Comment: with that i'm getting : Type 'Element | Element[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | null'. Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>': type, props, keyts(2322)

Comment: no help with this ?

Comment: Can you post where `Trans` is from, and can you also create a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post it (*you could use [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-ts)*) so we can test our suggestions.

Comment: that 'Trans' is imported from here : import { Trans } from "react-i18next";

Answer (score 2):

Typescript is automatically inferring `helperTextt`to be a string, if you are certain of its values you can get around this (although it is not preferred to declare type any) by declaring it as type any:

```
 let helperTextt:any;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add type to your `helperTextt`  variable

```
let helperTextt: JSX.Element = null;
```

Comment: then i'm getting 'Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element'.ts(2322)
'

Comment: try to assign nothing then
let helperTextt: JSX.Element;

Comment: then in other place i get error : Variable 'helperTextt' is used before being assigned.ts(2454)

Answer (score 0):

```
    let helperText: JSX.Element | string = "";

    if (event.target.id === "hostname") {
        if (!HOSTNAME_REGEX.test(event.target.value)) {
          helperText = (
            <Trans i18nKey="form.formData.hostNameError">
              Invalid Host name
            </Trans>
          );
          errorr = true;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's an issue related to the inferred type of a variable by Typescript itself, as in my case, I was using `title` as the name which was initially a string prop to a Component, but later declared it's type to `ReactElement` which gave this issue!
Well, to fix this, I just renamed the prop from `title` to `appTitle` and that worked like magic!